# Store intergers in tuple or list, with option of sorting each in ascending or descending order

Tags: python, list, sorting, integer, tuples

a beginner in python coding here, I try to construct a code below but do not know how to form it properly. I have tried some stuff for the ascending and descending order. Is there something that can merge the tuple and list sorting or they need to be done individually?

User enters at least 6 numbers separated by spaces. After input, the program asks three questions:

1: whether the entered numeric values should be stored in a tuple or a list.

2: whether the sequence should be sorted in ascending or descending order.

3: whether the sorted sequence should be returned in a list or tuple.

```
Code:

list =\[7,5,8,2,9,6,3,4,1\]
tup = (7,5,8,2,9,6,3,4,1)
n_tup=sorted(tup)
print("Tuple\\t",n_tup)

s_list = sorted(list, reverse=True)

print("sorted list variable:\\t", s_list)

list.sort()

print("original list variable:\\t",list)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Short answer:

No we don't have function in python that returns sorted tuple. Since tuple are immutable and therefore cannot be changed. And therefore, it will defeat the whole purpose of a tuple.

When you use `sorted` function on a tuple. It creates a copy of tuple and returns a list object.

##### Descriptive solution:

The problem here can be solved by changing the logic of code. Start the execution only after you have the answer to these questions:

1: whether the entered numeric values should be stored in a tuple or a list.

2: whether the sequence should be sorted in ascending or descending order.

3: whether the sorted sequence should be returned in a list or tuple.

So, once you know that user wants to [store | return] the value in a tuple. Do the sorting, which will return a sorted list. Then convert it to tuple.

After this, you will have all the conditions met, which are:

1. The values are `stored in a tuple`.
2. The values are `sorted`
3. The values are `returned in a tuple`.